# XEditable using PHP MySQL Update via Ajax: issue with updating different columns.

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, x-editable

I have multiple database columns but have stuck with two for now just to get two working (category and product).

As of now, I can update the category column, but I'm not sure how to implement my php so it will account for multiple columns.

Note. I can ONLY edit one database field at a time, and that is my intention.

Here is a simplified version of my HTML/php in question:

```
    echo '<td><span class="xedit" id="'.$propRow['id'].'">'.$propRow['category'].'</span></td>';
    echo '<td><span class="xedit xedit-product" id="'.$propRow['id'].'">'.$propRow['product'].'</span></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
    $rows []= array(
        'id' => $propRow['id']
    );
```

Here is my JS:

```
        var rowData = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;
        for (i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++){
            var rd = rowData[i].id;

            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                $('.xedit').editable({
                    tpl: '<input type="text" name="category" id="' + rd + '" class="test form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">'
                });
                $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
                    var num = $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
                    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
                    $.fn.editable.defaults.send = "always";
                    var values = $(".test").val();
                    var myObj = { id: num, category: values };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'post.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: myObj,
                        success: {}
                    }); 
                });
            });

        }
```

My post.php file is here (And I think this is where the issue lies. Please refrain from commenting on the usage of mysql_* functions):

```
<?php
    include '../config/database.php';
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $product = $_POST['category'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE " . $usoc_table . " SET category='" . $category . "', product='" . $product . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "';";
    mysql_query($query);
?>
```

What type of conditionals do I need to set up in post.php to get this working? I've toyed around with isset and !empty but have not had much luck.

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to come up with a solution, although not the prettiest.

First, give each column item a separate class, like so (before I was just using .xedit).

```
echo '<td><span class="xedit-category" id="'.$propRow['id'].'">'.$propRow['category'].'</span></td>';
echo '<td><span class="xedit-product" id="'.$propRow['id'].'">'.$propRow['product'].'</span></td>';
```

Next, use `.edtiable({})` separately per class and use `tpl` per each. As you can see each one has a different `name=`

```
$('.xedit-category').editable({
    tpl: '<input type="text" name="category" id="' + rd + '" class="cat form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">'
});
$('.xedit-product').editable({
    tpl: '<input type="text" name="product" id="' + rd + '" class="prod form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">'
});
```

Then, get the values per class:

```
var valuesCat = $(".cat").val();
var valuesProd = $(".prod").val();
```

Set up an obj `myObj` that will have the same id every time but a different 2nd key (in this case, `myObj.category` and `myObj.product`

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.id = num;

if ($("input").hasClass("prod")){
    myObj.product = valuesProd;
}
if ($("input").hasClass("cat")){
    myObj.category = valuesCat;
}
```

Throw that into `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: myObj,
    success:...
```

And finally in post.php, have two separate update queries:

```
 if (isset($_POST['category'])) {
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $query = "UPDATE " . $usoc_table . " SET category='" . $category . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "';";
        mysql_query($query);
 }

 if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
        $product = $_POST['product'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $query = "UPDATE " . $usoc_table . " SET product='" . $product . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "';";
        mysql_query($query);
 }
```

Not the most elegant by any means and quite repetitive, but got the job done for now.

Any input on how to refactor this is greatly appreciated.